# javax.mail.BodyPart getfileName returns null

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime-types, mime, mime-message

I am trying to read Content Type with

```
javax.mail.Multipart multipart = (MimeMultipart) mimeMessage.getContent(); //javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(index);
```

as the content type breaks into two line, it returns filename as Null ( I asssume 80 character max limit is causing this)

Note : it works fine, if i move the name manually on the same line.

**is there any way to control this behavior ?**

This one I am able to read filename

```
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="abcdefghijk Application-Henry Gotter.pdf"
Content-Description: abcdefghijk Application-Henry Gotter.pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="abcdefghijk Application-Henry Gotter.pdf"; size=418197;
creation-date="Fri, 09 Mar 2018 14:59:50 GMT";
modification-date="Thu, 22 Mar 2018 13:40:06 GMT"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

This one I am unable to read filename

```
Content-Type: application/pdf;
name="abcdefghijk Suitability - Henry Gotter.pdf"
Content-Description: abcdefghijk Suitability - Henry Gotter.pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="abcdefghijk Suitability - Henry Gotter.pdf"; size=418960;
creation-date="Fri, 09 Mar 2018 15:03:07 GMT";
modification-date="Thu, 22 Mar 2018 13:40:07 GMT"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `name=` and `filename=` really on their own lines? If not, then please edit question and show the *real* headers. If so, then that's bad headers, because a linefeed ends a header *line*. Fix the code that generates the header lines to not break a header **line** into two *lines*.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,I have updated the question with two headers in the same email file, first one I am able to read filename while other returns null

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt), section 2.2.3. Long Header Fields:

> Each header field is logically a single line of characters comprising the field name, the colon, and the field body.  For convenience however, and to deal with the 998/78 character limitations per line, the field body portion of a header field can be split into a multiple line representation; this is called "folding".  The general rule is that wherever this standard allows for folding white space (not simply WSP characters), a CRLF may be inserted **before** any WSP.
>
> For example, the header field:
>
> ```
> Subject: This is a test
> ```
>
> can be represented as:
>
> ```
> Subject: This
>  is a test
> ```

So, the continuation lines, e.g. `name=` must begin with a space.

The headers you've shown are **invalid**. Fix the code that generated them.